# Error: Java heap space Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs

```
Error: Java heap space Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143.

The hadoop cluster has 3 machines, one of them is the master,others are datanode,the machine's RAM is 8G.

the yarn-site.xml:


  <configuration>

    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
   <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>Hadoop1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
         <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
          <value>4096</value>
    </property>
     <property>
          <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
          <value>2048</value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
          <value>false</value>
           <description>Whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for    containers</description>
    </property>

    <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
         <value>4</value>
         <description>Ratio between virtual memory to physical memory when setting memory limits for containers</description>
</property>


</configuration>



the mapred-site.xml:

<configuration>

   <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
   <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
        <value>hadoop1:10020</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
       <value>hadoop1:19888</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
       <value>/user</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive</name>
         <value>true</value>        
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
         <value>2048</value>        
     </property>  
     <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
         <value>4096</value>        
     </property> 
  <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
         <value>-Xmx1024m</value>        
     </property>  
     <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
         <value>-Xmx3072m</value>        
     </property> 


</configuration>``
```

when I run the mapreduce,get the error:Error: Java heap space Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143.

The input files are 500M,the reduce number is 4. when the input files less then 300M, the program can run good.

Comment: Does you job fail in mapper or reducer phase?

Comment: in the reducer phase,all in the reuduce 70%-99% failed.